# Updating records missing from clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

With this query, I'm getting an error

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "inv"
LINE 1: update stock_picking set invoice_status = inv.date_invoice
```

My goal is to set stock_picking posting_date to inv.date_invoice if it meets all conditions, is it possible with SQL?

```sql
update stock_picking set posting_date = inv.date_invoice
where id in 
(
SELECT DISTINCT sp.id
FROM stock_picking sp
                       INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON sp.id = sm.picking_id
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol ON sm.sale_line_id = sol.id 
                       INNER JOIN sale_order so ON sol.order_id = so.id
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel so_inv_rel on so.id = so_inv_rel.order_id
                       INNER JOIN account_invoice inv on so_inv_rel.invoice_id = inv.id

    WHERE 

            sp.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
            and sm.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
            and sp.state = 'done'       
            and inv.state in ('open', 'paid')
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
update stock_picking S set posting_date = A.date_invoice
from 
(
SELECT DISTINCT sp.id, inv.date_invoice
FROM stock_picking sp
                       INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON sp.id = sm.picking_id
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol ON sm.sale_line_id = sol.id 
                       INNER JOIN sale_order so ON sol.order_id = so.id
                       INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel so_inv_rel on so.id = so_inv_rel.order_id
                       INNER JOIN account_invoice inv on so_inv_rel.invoice_id = inv.id

    WHERE 

            sp.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
            and sm.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
            and sp.state = 'done'       
            and inv.state in ('open', 'paid')
            ) A where S.id=A.id
```

Comment: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous
LINE 18:             ) A where id=A.id 
                               ^

Answer (score 1):

You need a `UPDATE ... FROM` to be able to reference the column from inside the query in the update. Connect them in the `WHERE` clause later.

```
UPDATE stock_picking u SET posting_date = t.date_invoice
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (sp.id) 
    sp.id, inv.date_invoice
  FROM stock_picking sp
  INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON sp.id = sm.picking_id
  INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol ON sm.sale_line_id = sol.id 
  INNER JOIN sale_order so ON sol.order_id = so.id
  INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel so_inv_rel on so.id = so_inv_rel.order_id
  INNER JOIN account_invoice inv on so_inv_rel.invoice_id = inv.id
  WHERE 
    sp.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
    and sm.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
    and sp.state = 'done'       
    and inv.state in ('open', 'paid')
  ORDER BY sp.id, inv.date_invoice DESC
) t
WHERE u.id = t.id
```

Since I don't know your model, I've assumed that relationship between `stock_picking` and `account_invoice` may be 1:N thus using `DISTINCT ON` will return only one `date_invoice` for each `id`. You could use `GROUP BY` + `MAX/MIN` aggregate function to achieve the same result.

Notice the usage of `t` and `u` table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error as the update query is trying to get data from the `inv` table which isn't joined at all.

You are able to do joins on update queries as well.

```
update sp
set posting_date = inv.date_invoice
from stock_picking as sp
inner join account_invoice inv on ***whatever columns link the tables together***
where id in 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT sp.id
    FROM stock_picking sp
        INNER JOIN stock_move sm ON sp.id = sm.picking_id
        INNER JOIN sale_order_line sol ON sm.sale_line_id = sol.id 
        INNER JOIN sale_order so ON sol.order_id = so.id
        INNER JOIN sale_order_invoice_rel so_inv_rel on so.id = so_inv_rel.order_id
        INNER JOIN account_invoice inv on so_inv_rel.invoice_id = inv.id
    WHERE 
        sp.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
        and sm.posting_date != inv.date_invoice
        and sp.state = 'done'       
        and inv.state in ('open', 'paid')
)
```